# How can a where filter be added to ToList in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm pretty new to C# and ASP.NET and I have some source code from my current project that I want to expand.

Its a website with a database in the background running where the source of the information inside the site is stored (since it changes often). For the menu bar so far we only had 1 segment, so we just loaded in all the categories:
`List<Category> categories = (from x in db.Categories select x).ToList();`

But now we added segments for different categories, how can I filter for the my specific segment? We defined the segment with a foreign key, is there something as easy as adding a `where db.Categories.SID = 1`?

Comment: Yep but its double equals and it goes between the from and select sections of the linq query. `var categories = db.Categories.Where(c=>c.SID == 1).ToList();` is another way to write the query in a bit easier form.

Comment: Did you try it? `from x in db.Categories where x.SID == 1 select x`

Comment: Microsoft has LINQ documented, so if you want to find out about it, checking the documentation is the first logical thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Category> categories = (from x in db.Categories where x.SID == 1 select x).ToList();
```

or

```
List<Category> categories = db.Categories.Where(c => c.SID == 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

The where filter can be added to the Linq expression, before you call ToList().
Try this:

```
List<Category> categories = (from x in db.Categories where x.SID == 1 select x).ToList();
```